# Java run time not found

Tags: java, jenkins, installation

I was trying to install jenkins in my MAC (MAC OS ).

After downloading jerkins file, while installing it is showing "Java Run time not found".

I have already downloaded Java 8.

Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pwKS.jpg)

Comment: is java on your path?

Comment: Downloaded AND installed?

Comment: yes its downloaded and installed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't added Java to your Path.
Basically you need to set your JAVA_HOME in the path for any Java applications to run and Jenkins is Java based application.

Check out the link below on steps to add JAVA_HOME to your Mac path

http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/